# filter by date range in R

Tags: r, date, filter

I have a list of names with multiple dates, I want to filter only by dates within my period of interest.
i have a df like this

```
    Name    Date
Luis    01/05/22
Luis    02/05/22
Luis    03/05/22
Luis    04/05/22
Luis    05/05/22
Pedro   01/05/22
Pedro   02/05/22
Pedro   03/05/22
Pedro   04/05/22
Pedro   05/05/22
Pedro   06/05/22
Pedro   07/05/22
Pedro   08/05/22
Pedro   09/05/22
Pedro   10/05/22
John    03/05/22
John    04/05/22
John    05/05/22
John    06/05/22
John    07/05/22
John    08/05/22
Ingrid  01/05/22
Ingrid  02/05/22
Ingrid  03/05/22
Ingrid  04/05/22
Ingrid  05/05/22
```

and another with time periods:

```
Name    Onset   End
Luis    01/05/22    03/05/22
Pedro   04/05/22    10/05/22
John    03/05/22    06/05/22
Ingrid  01/05/22    04/05/22
```

and I expect a result already filtered like the following:

```
Name    Date
Luis    01/05/22
Luis    02/05/22
Luis    03/05/22
Pedro   04/05/22
Pedro   05/05/22
Pedro   06/05/22
Pedro   07/05/22
Pedro   08/05/22
Pedro   09/05/22
Pedro   10/05/22
John    03/05/22
John    04/05/22
John    05/05/22
John    06/05/22
Ingrid  01/05/22
Ingrid  02/05/22
Ingrid  03/05/22
Ingrid  04/05/22
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the 'date' columns to `Date` class, do a join by 'Name' and `filter` after creating a logical expression with `<=`, `>=`

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
df1 %>% 
  left_join(df2) %>%
  filter(dmy(Date) >= dmy(Onset), dmy(Date) <= dmy(End)) %>% 
  select(-c(Onset, End))
```

-output

```
  Name     Date
1    Luis 01/05/22
2    Luis 02/05/22
3    Luis 03/05/22
4   Pedro 04/05/22
5   Pedro 05/05/22
6   Pedro 06/05/22
7   Pedro 07/05/22
8   Pedro 08/05/22
9   Pedro 09/05/22
10  Pedro 10/05/22
11   John 03/05/22
12   John 04/05/22
13   John 05/05/22
14   John 06/05/22
15 Ingrid 01/05/22
16 Ingrid 02/05/22
17 Ingrid 03/05/22
18 Ingrid 04/05/22
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Name = c("Luis", "Luis", "Luis", "Luis", "Luis", 
"Pedro", "Pedro", "Pedro", "Pedro", "Pedro", "Pedro", "Pedro", 
"Pedro", "Pedro", "Pedro", "John", "John", "John", "John", "John", 
"John", "Ingrid", "Ingrid", "Ingrid", "Ingrid", "Ingrid"), Date = c("01/05/22", 
"02/05/22", "03/05/22", "04/05/22", "05/05/22", "01/05/22", "02/05/22", 
"03/05/22", "04/05/22", "05/05/22", "06/05/22", "07/05/22", "08/05/22", 
"09/05/22", "10/05/22", "03/05/22", "04/05/22", "05/05/22", "06/05/22", 
"07/05/22", "08/05/22", "01/05/22", "02/05/22", "03/05/22", "04/05/22", 
"05/05/22")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -26L))

df2 <- structure(list(Name = c("Luis", "Pedro", "John", "Ingrid"),
 Onset = c("01/05/22", 
"04/05/22", "03/05/22", "01/05/22"), End = c("03/05/22", "10/05/22", 
"06/05/22", "04/05/22")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```